# How to tell if response content is a text?

Tags: node.js

How to check if the response is plain text or if it is binary data that cannot be rendered in the browser as text?

```
http.get(url, function (response) {
    if (response.statusCode == 404) {
        // Resource not found
    } else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        //response.on('data', function (data) {
        //    
        //});
    } else {
        throw new Error('Unspecified.');
    }
}).on('error', reject);
```

In case of a binary file, I would not like to download the entire stream.

I would like to avoid relying on headers, because simply checking `text/*` would produce false positives (e.g. application/json).

Comment: Have you checked `response.headers['Content-Type']`?

Comment: I did say in the question that I would like to avoid relying on the headers. The headers are sever sent and can be anything. I would like to know if there is a way to analyse the first 100 bytes, or something along those lines, to determine content type.

Comment: What's wrong with relying on headers? Just create a mimetype mapping for known text types. You're not limited to checking _only_ for `text/*`... your filter can be as complex as you'd like.